# How to create a conversation from the messages in inbox,sent,draft database of android

Tags: java, android, sms

[See the picture below and i want to create a conversation like this i can do the designing part but i need to create a database for the messages to be in conversation format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pmrI.jpg)

See the picture below and i want to create a conversation like this i can do the designing part but i need to create a database for the messages to be in conversation format

messaging.java

< private static String LIST_SEPARATOR = "!@#$%^&*1234__/-|:..:|-/__*4321&^%$#@!";

```
public List<String> phno= new ArrayList<>();
public List<String> nam=new ArrayList<>();
public List<String> message=new ArrayList<>();
public List<String> time=new ArrayList<>();
public List<String> type=new ArrayList<>();
public List<String> lstMsg=new ArrayList<>();
public List<String> lstTime=new ArrayList<>();
public List<String> lstType=new ArrayList<>();
public List<String> tempMsg=new ArrayList<>();
public List<String> tempTime=new ArrayList<>();
public List<String> tempKind=new ArrayList<>();

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    String  address;

    String[] reqCols = new String[]{"_id", "thread_id", "address", "person", "date", "body", "type"};

    Uri URI;

    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

    String[] columns = new String[]{"address", "person", "date", "body", "type"};

    Cursor cursor1;

    int i,c=0;


    //gets phone numbers
    //inbox
    URI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
    cursor1 = cr.query(URI, reqCols, null, null, null);
    if (cursor1.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cursor1.moveToNext()) {
            address = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(columns[0]));

            for (i = 0; i < phno.size(); i++){
                if(address.equals(phno.get(i))) {
                    c++;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(c==0)
                phno.add(address);
            else
                c=0;

        }
    }
    cursor1.close();




    //sentbox
    URI = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent");
    cursor1 = cr.query(URI,reqCols, null, null, null);
    if (cursor1.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cursor1.moveToNext()){
            address = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(columns[0]));

            for (i = 0; i < phno.size(); i++){
                if(address.equals(phno.get(i))) {
                    c++;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(c==0)
                phno.add(address);
            else
                c=0;

        }
    }
    cursor1.close();


    //Draft
    URI = Uri.parse("content://sms/draft");
    cursor1 = cr.query(URI,reqCols, null, null, null);
    if (cursor1.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cursor1.moveToNext()){
            address = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(columns[0]));
            for (i = 0; i < phno.size(); i++){
                if(address.equals(phno.get(i))) {
                    c++;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(c==0)
                phno.add(address);
            else
                c=0;

        }
    }
    cursor1.close();



    //gets contact name
    for(i=0;i<phno.size();i++){
        nam.add(getContactName(this,phno.get(i)));
    }


    for(String temp:phno){

        URI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
        cursor1 = cr.query(URI, reqCols, null, null, null);
        if (cursor1.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cursor1.moveToNext()) {
                address = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(columns[0]));
                if(address.equals(temp)) {
                    tempTime.add(cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(columns[2])));// adds date
                    tempMsg.add(cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(columns[3])));// adds message
                    tempKind.add(cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(columns[4])));

                }


            }
        }
        cursor1.close();

        URI = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent");
        cursor1 = cr.query(URI, reqCols, null, null, null);
        if (cursor1.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cursor1.moveToNext()) {
                address = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(columns[0]));
                if(address.equals(temp)) {
                    tempTime.add(cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(columns[2])));// adds date
                    tempMsg.add(cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(columns[3])));// adds message
                    tempKind.add(cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(columns[4])));

                }


            }
        }
        cursor1.close();

        URI = Uri.parse("content://sms/draft");
        cursor1 = cr.query(URI, reqCols, null, null, null);
        if (cursor1.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cursor1.moveToNext()) {
                address = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(columns[0]));
                if(address.equals(temp)) {
                    tempTime.add(cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(columns[2])));// adds date
                    tempMsg.add(cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(columns[3])));// adds message
                    tempKind.add(cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(columns[4])));// adds type

                }


            }
        }
        cursor1.close();


        sort();

        lstTime.add(tempTime.get(tempTime.size()-1));
        lstMsg.add(tempMsg.get(tempMsg.size()-1));
        lstType.add(tempKind.get(tempKind.size()-1));

        time.add(convertListToString(tempTime));
        message.add(convertListToString(tempMsg));
        type.add(convertListToString(tempKind));



    }

    finalSort();











    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

//finds contact name
public static String getContactName(Context context, String phoneNumber) {
    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(uri, new String[]{ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) {
        return null;
    }
    String contactName = null;
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        contactName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
    }

    if(cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
        cursor.close();
    }

    return contactName;
}

// Converts ArrayList to string
public static String convertListToString(List<String> stringList) {
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    for (String str : stringList) {
        stringBuffer.append(str).append(LIST_SEPARATOR);
    }

    // Remove last separator
    int lastIndex = stringBuffer.lastIndexOf(LIST_SEPARATOR);
    stringBuffer.delete(lastIndex, lastIndex + LIST_SEPARATOR.length() + 1);

    return stringBuffer.toString();
}

// Converts String to ArrayList
public static List<String> convertStringToList(String str) {
    return Arrays.asList(str.split(LIST_SEPARATOR));
}

//Lists Sorting
public void sort(){


    for(int j=0;j<tempTime.size();j++){
        for(int i=j+1;i<tempTime.size();i++){
            if((tempTime.get(i)).compareTo(tempTime.get(j))<0){
                String t1 = tempTime.get(j);
                String t2 = tempKind.get(j);
                String t3 = tempMsg.get(j);

                tempTime.set( j, tempTime.get(i));
                tempTime.set(i,t1);

                tempKind.set( j, tempKind.get(i));
                tempKind.set(i,t2);

                tempMsg.set( j, tempMsg.get(i));
                tempMsg.set(i,t3);
            }
        }



    }
}

//Final
//Lists Sorting
public void finalSort(){


    for(int j=0;j<lstTime.size();j++){
        for(int i=j+1;i<lstTime.size();i++){
            if((lstTime.get(i)).compareTo(lstTime.get(j))<0){

                String t1 = lstTime.get(j);
                String t2 = lstMsg.get(j);
                String t3 = lstType.get(j);
                String t4 = time.get(j);
                String t5 = message.get(j);
                String t6 = type.get(j);
                String t7 = phno.get(j);
                String t8 = nam.get(j);

                lstTime.set( j, lstTime.get(i));
                lstTime.set(i,t1);

                lstMsg.set( j, lstMsg.get(i));
                lstMsg.set(i,t2);

                lstType.set( j, lstType.get(i));
                lstType.set(i,t3);

                time.set( j, time.get(i));
                time.set(i,t4);

                message.set( j, message.get(i));
                message.set(i,t5);

                type.set( j, type.get(i));
                type.set(i,t6);

                phno.set( j, phno.get(i));
                phno.set(i,t7);

                nam.set( j, nam.get(i));
                nam.set(i,t8);

            }
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: Please, be more specific. StackOverflow is neither code reviewing, debugging or code writing service.

Comment: Sorry sir for not being specific

Comment: I am building a messaging app with conversation but i am not getting how to create a conversation please need help

Comment: Consider reading [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), paying attention to how important is that your question does not look too broad, like “Design something for me” or “Write some code for me”, or seeking for recommendations, but rather focuses on a particular programming issue that others may answer with a relatively short (not necessarily one-line) answer.